# How to add a timeout to an awaiting function call

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency

What's the best way to add a timeout to an awaiting function?

```
Example:

/// lets pretend this is in a library that I'm using and I can't mess with the guts of this thing
func fetchSomething() async -> Thing? {
    // fetches something
}

// if fetchSomething() never returns then doSomethingElse() is never ran. Is there anyway to add a timeout to this system?
let thing = await fetchSomething()
doSomethingElse()
```

I wanted to make the system more robust in the case that fetchSomething() never returns. If this was using combine, I'd use the timeout operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can create a `Task`, and then `cancel` it if it has not finished in a certain period of time. E.g., launch two tasks in parallel:

```swift
// cancel the fetch after 2 seconds

func fetchThingWithTimeout() async throws -> Thing {
    let fetchTask = Task {
        try await self.fetchThing()                           // start fetch
    }

    let timeoutTask = Task {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))                // timeout in 2 seconds
        fetchTask.cancel()
    }

    return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {            // handle cancelation by caller of `fetchThingWithTimeout`
        let result = try await fetchTask.value
        timeoutTask.cancel()

        return result
    } onCancel: {
        fetchTask.cancel()
        timeoutTask.cancel()
    }
}

// here is a random mockup that will take between 1 and 3 seconds to finish

func fetchThing() async throws -> Thing {
    let duration: TimeInterval = .random(in: 1...3)
    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(duration))
    return Thing()
}
```

If the `fetchTask` finishes first, it will reach the `timeoutTask.cancel` and stop it. If `timeoutTask` finishes first, it will cancel the `fetchTask`.

Obviously, this rests upon the implementation of the `fetchThing` function. It should not only detect the cancelation, but also throw an error (likely a [`CancellationError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cancellationerror/)) if it was canceled. We cannot comment further without details regarding the implementation of `fetchTask`.

For example, in the above example, rather than returning an optional `Thing?`, I would instead return `Thing`, but have it `throw` an error if it was canceled.

---

Note, that [`withTaskCancellationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withtaskcancellationhandler(operation:oncancel:)/) is required because we used [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency), where cancelation is not automatically propagated for us. We have to handle that manually. You can, alternatively, remain within structured concurrency using a task group:

```swift
func fetchThingWithTimeout() async throws -> Thing {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Thing.self) { group in
        group.addTask {
            try await self.fetchThing()                       // start fetch
        }

        group.addTask {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))            // timeout in 2 seconds
            throw CancellationError()
        }

        guard let value = try await group.next() else {       // see if fetch succeeded …
            throw FetchError.noData                           // theoretically, it should not be possible to get here (as we either return a value or throw an error), but just in case
        }

        group.cancelAll()                                     // … but if we successfully fetched a value, cancel the timeout task, and
        return value                                          // … return value
    }
}
```

---

I hesitate to mention it, but while the above assumes that `fetchThing` was well-behaved (i.e., cancelable), there are permutations on the pattern that work even if it does not (i.e., run `doSomethingElse` in some reasonable timetable even if `fetchThing` “never returns”).

But this is an inherently unstable situation, as the resources used by `fetchThing` cannot be recovered until it finishes. Swift does not offer preemptive cancelation, so while we can easily solve the tactical issue of making sure that `doSomethingElse` eventually runs, if `fetchThing` might never finish in some reasonable timetable, you have deeper problem.

You really should find a rendition of `something` that is cancelable, if it is not already.

Comment: As you advised, I'm updating the example to make the fetch cancellable but I'm running into an issue where Task.isCancelled is false event though the function is being cancelled. I'm following the guide here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-cancel-a-task

Comment: This worked for me but only after applying the modifications here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75019438/swift-have-a-timeout-for-async-await-function

Comment: `Task.sleep` will, if canceled, will throw a `CancellationError`. So do the `async` functions of `URLSession`. Any well written `async` function should (though this is overlooked in many home-spun `async` function that you see on StackOverflow). Even when interfacing with some cancelable legacy API, we try to wrap it in  [`withTaskCancellationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withtaskcancellationhandler(operation:oncancel:)).

Answer (score -3):

//    You can use 'try and catch'. Wait for the fetch data inside the try block. When it fails the catch block can run a different statement. Something like this:

```
    await getResource() 
    try {
        await fetchData();
    } catch(err){
        doSomethingElse();
    }
    // program continues
```

Comment: FetchData doesn't have that capability. There's no time out on it.

Comment: Don't you think the fetchData() will either succeed or fail. Does it really need a time out? @Biclops