# Swift: Have a timeout for async/await function

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, timeout

Is there a way to attach a timeout to stop an async function if it takes too long?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
func search() async -> ResultEnum {
  // Call multiple Apis one after the other
}

Task.init {
  let searchResult = await search() 
  switch searchResult {
    // Handle all result scenarios
  }
}
```

I would like to have a deadline for the `search() async` function to provide a result, otherwise it should terminate and return `ResultEnum.timeout`.

Comment: I better use DispatchItem for this scenario.. Bcz it has feature to cancel any task

Comment: You might find this useful: https://forums.swift.org/t/running-an-async-task-with-a-timeout/49733 just make sure you use a “deadline” and not a “timeout”

Comment: Maybe you can shift _what_ times out from "function call" to "function execution". I.e. if you change `func search(maxDurationSec: Int)`, then inside function you can decide to stop. And since inside function you have URLSession tasks most likely, especially a chain one after the other, it's easy enough to check if overall execution time exceeded the limit, and stop / quit function.

Comment: Before you worry about timeout, you must first ensure that `search` is cancelable (and the fact that it isn’t throwing errors suggests that it isn’t). Is it cancelable?

Comment: Hi @Rob, I can make it cancelable. Can you provide an answer on how to implement my request to a cancelable async func?

Comment: Hi @flatasearth thanks for your reply. I don’t mind moving the deadline to function execution. How can I check if the execution time inside the func exceeded time limit, and stop it?

Comment: Once you make `search` cancelable (i.e., have it stop when canceled and presumably throw a `CancellationError`), then wrapping this in some timeout logic is not too bad. You just create one task for the `search`, create another task that will `cancel` the search task after a certain period of time, and whichever task finishes first will cancel the other one. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74712760/1271826.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thank you Rob for your comments, and for the link you provided.

I had to make some changes though, For some reason the initial task `fetchTask` kept going even after cancellation, until I added `Task.checkCancellation()` to it.

Here's what the code looks like now, if anyone is facing a similar issue:

```swift
func search() async throws -> ResultEnum {
  // This is the existing method as per my initial question.
  // It calls multiple Apis one after the other, then returns a result.
}

// Added the below method to introduce a deadline for search()
func search(withTimeoutSecs: Int) async {
    let fetchTask = Task {
        let taskResult = try await search()
        try Task.checkCancellation()
        // without the above line, search() kept going until server responded long after deadline.
        return taskResult
    }
        
    let timeoutTask = Task {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(withTimeoutSecs) * NSEC_PER_SEC)
        fetchTask.cancel()
    }
        
    do {
        let result = try await fetchTask.value
        timeoutTask.cancel()
        return result
    } catch {
        return ResultEnum.failed(NetworkError.timeout)
    }
}
```

---

```swift
// Call site: Using the function (withTimeout:) instead of ()
Task.init {
    let searchResult = await search(withTimeoutSecs: 6) 
    switch searchResult {
      // Handle all result scenarios
    }
}
```

Comment: A cancelable, throwing, `async` function should generally, itself, throw a [`CancellationError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cancellationerror/) if canceled. The burden for `try Task.checkCancellation()` should not generally fall upon the shoulders of the caller. IMHO, the problem rests in your `search` function. But, obviously, if `search` was not written in a way to properly handle cancelation, then I guess you have to do what you have to do.

Comment: We need to see `search` implementation to comment further.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what type of timeout you need but
I made one of the timeout approaches.
This approach raises cancel of the current task by timeout occurring and moving forward discarding awaiting the task.

Canceling tasks is not actually stopping current operations it’s just fact that telling them it’s canceled.

Below code calling cancel to task but “done” print will be done after longOperation has been finished except the operation has handling for cancel.

```swift
let task = Task {
  await longOperation()
  print("done")
}

...

task.cancel()
```

So let’s imagine the following case

```swift
await fetchFlag() // want this to make timeout in 5sec.

applyFlag()
```

This case needs a timeout for fetching the flag in 5sec in any case.
Whether raising canceling makes actually stop the current operation and pop out their step is up to the implementation.
To make timeout anyway at all costs of discarding handling them.
(So actually fetch request is still ongoing but moving forward anyway because it’s timed out.)

```swift
await withTimeout(5) {
  await fetchFlag() // want this to make timeout in 5sec.
}

applyFlag() // apply new flag or current flag if timeout occurred.
```

To achieve this behavior, needs harness unstructured concurrency API inside.

```swift
public enum TimeoutHandlerError: Error {
  case timeoutOccured
}

@_unsafeInheritExecutor
public func withTimeout<Return: Sendable>(
  nanoseconds: UInt64,
  @_inheritActorContext _ operation: @escaping @Sendable () async throws -> Return
) async throws -> Return {

  let task = Ref<Task<(), Never>>(value: nil)
  let timeoutTask = Ref<Task<(), any Error>>(value: nil)

  let flag = Flag()

  return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {

    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Return, Error>) in

      do {
        try Task.checkCancellation()
      } catch {
        continuation.resume(throwing: error)
        return
      }

      let _task = Task {
        do {
          let taskResult = try await operation()

          await flag.performIf(expected: false) {
            continuation.resume(returning: taskResult)
            return true
          }
        } catch {
          await flag.performIf(expected: false) {
            continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            return true
          }
        }
      }

      task.value = _task

      let _timeoutTask = Task {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: nanoseconds)
        _task.cancel()

        await flag.performIf(expected: false) {
          continuation.resume(throwing: TimeoutHandlerError.timeoutOccured)
          return true
        }

      }

      timeoutTask.value = _timeoutTask
    }
  } onCancel: {
    task.value?.cancel()
    timeoutTask.value?.cancel()
  }
}


private final class Ref<T>: @unchecked Sendable {
  var value: T?

  init(value: T?) {
    self.value = value
  }
}

private actor Flag {
  var value: Bool = false

  func set(value: Bool) {
    self.value = value
  }

  func performIf(expected: Bool, perform: @Sendable () -> Bool) {
    if value == expected {
      value = perform()
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/muukii/swift-async-timeout/blob/main/Sources/swift-async-timeout/swift_async_timeout.swift

Comment: Nice. But what's the point of `flag` if it's never set?

Comment: sorry. `func set(value: Bool) {` is not used but performIf gets the result value from perform closure. this sets the value.